# Empty Folder List from a Given Input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, scripting-language

I have a directory that contain logs for each day. Each directory is formated with this name pattern `2012_07_01` , `2012_07_02`.

What I want is to check from a given `$startdate` and a `$enddate`, and see if between any of that time from the start and enddate variables exists empty folders on the return list of the search. If that is the case then I remove the empty folders from my list of returned values.

AS for the ones that have files inside them I want to search each one of them for the `$startdate` and `$enddate` values. If they exist in any of the directories then I want the script to return me with that list of filenames.

Comment: This question has some room for improvement -- Do use punctuation and appropriate capitalisation, and do share what you're tried so far.

Comment: Do the directories have correct time stamps? It would be easier to do it with `find -ctime`.

Comment: hmm i'm not quite sure what you mean but correct by what i can tell you is all in the all the directories have that name from 2012_07_01 to today date 2012_11_09,  and its a folder that is created for each day ,manually ,by another person that make sure that all the log files from that day have the correct size and quality and content , then that person move it to the correct folder in this case the logs for each day inside the day they were created. So i guess the answer is yes they have the correct time stamp

Comment: can you define the -ctime for the startdate variable?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

```
for dir in `ls | sort | sed -n "/$startdate/,/$enddate/p"` ; do
  if [ `ls $dir | wc -l` -gt 0 ] ; then
    ls $dir
  else
    rmdir $dir
  fi
done
```

Also, note that `rmdir *` will only remove empty directories.